# List all occurences of a particular string or number in the file : UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, awk, filter, grep

I have multiple files containing phone numbers in a format XXX XXX XXXX or  +XX XXXXXX XXXX or maybe XXXXXXXXXX. Can I list all the phone numbers containing particular no. '845' against each file name.

Currently I am using:-

```
egrep -H 845 *
```

Comment: Provide a sample data of your input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you want (uses GNU for word delimiters):

```
$ cat file
now is the 123 845 1234 winter of +01 238456 5432
our 1845234567 discontent.

$ cat tst.awk         
{
    while ( match($0,/(\<(([0-9]{3} ){2}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{10})|[+][0-9]{2} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4})\>/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        if ( tgt ~ /845/ ) {
            print tgt
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
123 845 1234
+01 238456 5432
1845234567
```

If not, edit your question to provide some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk '/845/ {print FILENAME,FNR,$0}' *
```

Or this:

```
grep -rF '845' *
```

This does not give you hits only on phone number, but all line with this nubers.
You does not tell if this is middle of a number, start or end.

Comment: phone numbers are randomly placed in the text. It is kind of log files.

Comment: There are thousand of lines. I need to dig specifically only the number. Not the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

To list the surrounding numbers around the match but nothing else,

```
grep -Ho '[0-9]*845[0-9]*' files
```

If your phone numbers can contain spaces and punctuation, maybe add those to the [character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes); but be careful so as not to make the regex match two adjacent phone numbers in one go.  (If they are always separated by text not in the character class, you're fine.)

(There is nothing [`-E`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) in this particular regex so I'm not using `egrep`.)

Comment: This may fail on numbers like `348 453 1234` or `01 123484 5983` both have `845` within, but have space between them. This may do `grep -Ho '[0-9 ]*8 *4 *5[0-9 ]*`, but my give problem if you have number `348 123 1458 4598 east street`.